# How to use Response.Redirect in asp.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created an application with master page in which on `button_click` it needs to navigate from one page to another using `Response.Redirect`. Suggest some solutions to me.

Comment: we can't help you for what is 1+1.We are not Entertaining these kind of question.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more? Do you want to redirect to one particular page or to different page that user chooses? And, why would you want to use Response.Redirect? Why not asp:Hyperlink or plain <a href=""> tag?

Comment: I have an button at master page which should navigate on button click to content page. But should not use post back url. Is this elaboration enough???

Comment: @user1216041 if any of the below were helpful please mark one as the answer

Answer (score 5):

Just use `Response.Redirect("new.aspx");`

Answer (score 2):

Personally I'd advise against this approach because of the number of trips to the server.

When you click a button it will post back, you will then send a Response.Redirect which will tell your browser to go to a different address.  The browser will then reload the page.  This requires two requests to the server.

A much cleaner approach is to use something like a LinkButton and set the PostBackUrl

Comment: But am not supposed to use post back url

Comment: If you have a requirement which says you can't use PostBackUrl then you should use Response.Redirect as described by @Sergey Gavruk - however be aware of the performance impacts of this.

Answer (score 0):

you could also use,

`return RedirectToAction("controller action for the view you wish to link to")`

e.g. `return RedirectToAction("Index")` or `return RedirectToAction("Details")`